# Does _update_by_query work with more than the 10,000 default limit?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add a new field (`Value`) to +10,000 entries stored on ElasticSearch, I came up with a query as follows:

```json
POST index/_update_by_query
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "Value"
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "script" : {
      "inline": "ctx._source.Value = 420;"
  }
}
```

AFAIK, when retrieving a high number of documents, we need to handle pagination by [scrolling/PIT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html), does the same principle apply on `_update_by_query`?

Comment: if you plan to run this on a large number of documents, I suggest running it with slices to increase concurrency, add `?slices=auto` (or any number) to the end of the URL.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-slice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to. The update by query endpoint does this for you in the background. It will scroll over all documents that match the query and update them according to your script and/or your pipeline.

Once a batch of documents has been updated, it fetches the next batch using the scroll API. So you don't need to care about it, even if you're about to update millions of documents.